# The word "and".

Tags: terminology

If I say

> the difference between $x$ **and** $y$

Does that mean $x - y$ or $y - x$ or $|x - y|$?

Comment: It depends. ${}$

Comment: What does it depend on?

Comment: On what you mean!

Comment: But I meant what I stated.

Comment: What you stated does not mean anything unambiguosly, so it cannot mean *that*.

Comment: Clearly, you understand that the phrase is ambiguous, so it  is quite unclear what you are after. The only sensible suggestion is: just do not say that.

Comment: It's worth noting that *because* there's an easier way to say $x-y$  (namely "$x$ minus $y$"), your best bet when reading something like this is to go with the interpretation of Andreas Blass and T. Bongers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were to say "the difference between $x$ and $y$," I would probably mean $|x-y|$, simply because the use of "between" suggests symmetry between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 5):

As Mariano pointed out, the meaning is somewhat ambiguous and subjective. It pretty much never hurts to add a word or two of clarification. If I personally use it, I'm usually referring to the difference in absolute terms, so $|x - y|$.